# Fixed range of timestamps for every uuid in SQL

Tags: postgresql

I would like to generate a table with the last n weeks timestamps of data (in this case, n=3) and all the data, even if it is null.

I am using the following pieces of code

```
   with raw_weekly_data as (SELECT
   distinct d.uuid,
   date_trunc('week',a.start_timestamp) as tstamp,
   avg(price) as price
   FROM
   a join d on a.uuid = d.uuid
   where start_timestamp between date_trunc('week',now()) -           interval '3 week' and date_trunc('week',now())
   group by 1,2,3
   order by 1)

   ,tstamp as (SELECT
   distinct tstamp
   FROM
   raw_weekly_data
   )

   SELECT
   t.tstamp,
   r.*
   from raw_weekly_data r right join tstamp t on r.tstamp =       t.tstamp
   order by uuid
```

I would like to have something like that:

```
week  |  uuid  | price
w1    |  1     | 10
w2    |  1     | 2
w3    |  1     |
w1    |  2     | 20
w2    |  2     |
w3    |  2     |
w1    |  3     | 10
w2    |  3     | 10
w3    |  3     | 20
```

But instead all the null results are not showed. What is the best approach in here?

```
week  |  uuid  | price
w1    |  1     | 10
w2    |  1     | 2
w1    |  2     | 20
w1    |  3     | 10
w2    |  3     | 10
w3    |  3     | 20
```

Comment: Perhaps you need `a left join d` . To know it for sure and give you a working solution, we would want you to add sample data for  tables `a` and `d`

Comment: Your question should start with your Postgres version and table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statement). Some sample data would also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form a Cartesian product of all weeks an UUIDs, *then* `LEFT JOIN` to actual avg, prices per `(week, uuid)`. Like:

```
SELECT *
FROM   generate_series (date_trunc('week', now() - interval '3 week')
                                         , now() - interval '1 week'
                      , interval '1 week') tstamp
CROSS  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT uuid FROM a) a
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT d.uuid
        , date_trunc('week', a.start_timestamp) AS tstamp
        , avg(price) AS price  -- d.price?
   FROM   a
   JOIN   d USING (uuid)
   WHERE  a.start_timestamp >= date_trunc('week',now()) - interval '3 week'
   AND    a.start_timestamp <  date_trunc('week',now())
   ) ad USING (uuid, tstamp)
GROUP  BY 1, 2
ORDER  BY 1, 2
```

This way you get *all* combinations of the last three weeks and UUIDs, extended by the average price - if one should exist for the combination.
Based on some educated guesses to fill in missing information ..